# What is the difference between bias and residuals?

Tags: regression, residuals, bias, estimators

I'm aware of the bias variance trade off.
Intuitively I understand how as the model becomes more complex the variance decreases and the bias increases, after a certain point.
But I don't really understand bias.

For example:

If we have a predictor variable x, and we want to estimate a y.

Bias = E[x] - y

residual = x*B - y <=> E[x] - y

Comment: “Bias" for parameters, "Residuals" for observations.

Comment: You've got your intuitions reversed: Bias is, roughly, the distance between what your model *says* E[Y | X] is and what it *really* is, so if you make a more complex model, e.g. by conditioning on more than X, this distance will in general get smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, a bias means that in average your estimate is off by some amount from the true value of the parameter. In application to residuals you have to understand that they are estimates of errors. In a model like this 
$$y=X\beta+\varepsilon$$
The last term is an error, and it's *not* observable. We can estimate the errors, and this estimate called *residuals* $\hat\varepsilon$. The bias in relation to residuals could mean that in average your residuals are off by some amount from errors: 
$$E[\hat\varepsilon]\ne 0$$
here, I assumed that errors are zero in average.

Usually, in the context of the regression the bias is considered for parameter estimates $\hat\beta$, not the residuals.

Note, that in the linear regression we usually include the intercept, thus, by construction, we make $$E[\hat\varepsilon|X]= 0$$

Comment: I think both residual and bias come from a similar concept. first is bias in predictions and second is bias in parameter.But we use term residual because it is more common in literature.

Comment: @Hamed if the model is correct, the residuals are nonzero (because of random variation). It would seem bizarre to call that bias.

Comment: @Glen_b agree but both follow the same concept one for a population parameter and another for observations.

Answer (score 2):

A bias is a property of an estimator or a statistics, NOT of a stochastic realization. It means that an estimator or a statistics is calculated in a way that it is SYSTEMATICALLY different from the quantity that is supposed to summarize / estimate.

These things are NOT examples of bias:

- Residuals for a single experiment
- The difference of a parameter estimate or prediction from the truth for a single experiment (unless it is systematic)
- Anything else that is stochastic and not systematic

The bias variance trade-off is maybe not an ideal name, it should maybe have better been called interpolation/extrapolation trade-off. Anyway, the motivation for the name is that that when adding more parameters / complexity, you have

- Less systematic error (bias) in your model (supposedly, because it is more flexible, I would argue it depends on what you call error / bias)
- More variance in the estimation of the model parameters (because it is more flexible)

Comment: +1. this answer also highlights the difference in how the concept is used by statisticians and machine learners (who in my experience often use it interchangeably with prediction error) .